# Facebook SDK: Post to a page as the page ID

Tags: c#, facebook, winforms, facebook-graph-api

I am able to post to one of my own pages in Facebook using the Facebook SDK and Winforms and C#.  However, when I post the photo or message or whatever, it shows that the item was posted by "Jim Tyminski" and not the page name "ListWithFreedom.com".  How do I get the post to show that it came from the group and not my personal ID?

Answer (score 0):

That is not even possible directly in the group, without the API. You can only post as a page (with the correct permissions and Access Token) or as a User (with the User Access Token).

Edit: Posting to a Page as the Page is possible, of course, you just need a **Page Access Token** instead of the User Access Token. That´s the only Token where you actually have to deal with Tokens, usually the handling is done by the SDKs out there.

Some useful Links:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

In general, you have to authorize the User with the "**manage_pages**" permission, and make an API call to "**/me/accounts**" to get the Page Access Token for your specific Page. With that Token, you can post as the Page.

Comment: Not true.   If I log on to FB using my browser, enter my group, I can change a setting that says "Post as ListWithFreedom.com"... Any thoughts?

Comment: Actually, you are right!  Sorry...  I was mistaken.  I meant to say "Page" not "Group"  Does that make a difference?

Comment: yeah, there is a big difference, pages and groups are completely different things. i will edit my answer to fit to pages. may be a good idea for you to change the question if this is not about groups but pages instead.